# How to log to application log and security log from the same application

Tags: logging, log4j, log4cxx

I have an application that needs to log "application log messages" to an appender and "security log messages" to another appender (security log messages cannot appear in the application log). I was thinking setting up my loggers like this:

```
Logger appLogger = Logger.getLogger("app." + myClassName);
Logger securityLogger = Logger.getLogger("security." + myClassName);
```

And setting my log4j configuration like this:

```
log4j.logger.app = DEBUG, applicationLogAppender
log4j.additivity.app = false 

log4j.logger.security = DEBUG, securityLogAppender
log4j.additivity.security = false
```

**What is the best way to configure log4j to do this?** I believe my solution will work and still gives developers the ability to enabled and disable logging for a specific package/class as long as they remember to prefix the package/class name with "app." or "security.", but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

*NOTE: The solution will need to work for log4j and log4cxx.*

Answer (score 0):

Two years ago I was given quite the same task and I proposed exactly this, only our logger prefixes were called "admin" and "debug". Your/mine suggestion sort of creates two independent top-level loggers, just below the root logger.

I don't think log4j/cxx allows the built-in root logger not to be configured. To block it from logging thrash from loggers that don't follow your naming policy, I'd set its log level to "OFF".